# Can not find a way to use TypeScript with function which redeclares windowStorage

Tags: typescript, local-storage

I have a perfectly working JS function that defines local storage the way I need (here you see a version with all but critical content removed for readability’s sake and only a single set method left for example):

```
class Mystorage  {
  constructor(){}
  
};

window.Storage = {
  local: new Mystorage(),
 
};
```

Now try to rewrite it to TS. What goes wrong is the part

```
window.Storage  = {
        local: new MyStorage(),
        
    };
```

I have written two interfaces to help me

```
interface MyStorage {
    local: globalThis.Storage;
    session: globalThis.Storage;
}

interface AnyStorage {
    local: any;
    session: any;
}
```

and tried to assign them like this:

```
window.Storage = {
        local: new Storage(),
        
    } as MyStorage
```

and with AnyStorage respectively (and also as any as Mystorage) but it keeps throwing an error

> Property 'prototype' is missing in type 'MyStorage' but required in type '{ new (): Storage; prototype: Storage; }'

and

> 'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type.

Could I ask someone to explain how should it be correctly handled? I know that it is nothing good at redefining global object elements, but it's already done, and now try to get out of the mess without rewriting it from the very beginning?

Comment: Why are you overriding the global [`Storage`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) class? That's why you're getting the first error.

Comment: Yes, expected such the question. In fact, I have developed that long time ago and as far as TS was not a matter it worked nicely. This way I avoid making function that would be interfacing between native localStorage and rest of App and I was happy with that. You must be right that this is a reason. But I have coded it like that.

Comment: The "correct" way to handle this is to rewrite your `Storage` implementation so that it is an actual ES2015+ `class` instead of a `function`, and don't clobber global `Storage`; monkey-patching JS with something incompatible is not something TS is going to support, for good reasons.  If you just want to suppress errors you can throw more type assertions at it.  In any case could you edit into a [mre] so that someone can drop it into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](//tsplay.dev/wg6e9W) without any unrelated errors?

Comment: If I drop that code into a TypeScript IDE [like this](https://tsplay.dev/wX2aom) I get a bunch of errors, only a few of which are what you're asking about. Could you resolve/eliminate the unrelated errors?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, done, however it hardly resembles original code

Comment: Since TS's [DOM library](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/c71ff4dcdf60c373ea0ccca56b112311470c38b0/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L14312-L14315) declares a global variable named `Storage` there's nothing easy to do here. You can't merge a new type into the existing variable (see [ms/TS#4062](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4062)) nor can you redeclare it (see [ms/TS#4062](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37771)). ...

Comment: ... You can either use a [forked version of the dom library with the Storage variable missing](//codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-tnm2t?file=/index.ts), or use [awful type assertions](//tsplay.dev/NaY3EN), or just [rename your global variable](https://tsplay.dev/mx60xw), which is by far the easiest and most correct way to proceed. Let me know if you want me to write these up as an answer.

Comment: @jcalz  Thank you, need some time to revise all of that

Comment: @jcalz Thank you, yes, definitely it is an aswer, no doubt, for my case.